stuck keyframes on dope sheet

I am trying to make an animation and the problem that I am encountering is that there are a few keyframes that i cant seem to delete inside the DOPE SHEET , they all are highlighted in yellow all the time, i don't have them locked or anything so I am having a really hard time understanding what is going on. I have tried deleting them from the action editor, still nothing changes, keyframes are still there and the rig ofc does what the keyframes are supposed to do

did u scroll down all the way? if yes, pls provide blend file so we can check it out.
